# mod rewrite errors

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I have a domain which shows like so

www.example.co.uk/index.php

Different sections of the site live in different phyical folders.  For example

www.example.co.uk/watersports/index.php?page=activities

watersports being the physical folder.

or

www.example.co.uk/health-and-fitness/index.php?page=the-gym

watersports being the physical folder.

I have tried to use a similar mod rewrite that I found on Stack which looks as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^/$1 /index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^/$1 /index.php
```

but it doesn't work.

Im trying to make the url look like this

www.example.co.uk/watersports/activities

www.example.co.uk/health-and-fitness/the-gym

Can anyone help

Comment: How rewritten URL should look ?
www.example.co.uk/watersports/activities ?

Comment: Hi @vince I have amended the comment.  Thanks for pointing that would   of rendered my question useless!

Comment: "Im trying to make the url look like this" `mod_rewrite` is not for creating URL's to friendly URL's. Those URL's you've mentioned must be created through your server side system. THey are just resolved via `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ $1/index.php?page=$2 [L]
```

On my computer it works pretty well, even with multiple sub folders like this :

```
http://localhost/experiment/stackoverflow-13377725/activities/foo
http://localhost/experiment/stackoverflow-13377725/activities/foo/bar
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I tried your code and it seems to sort of work.  Instead of explaining Ill just give you the web address to the site its www.crosbylakeside.co.uk

Comment: as you can see.  on the root page the mod rewrite works but any down line pages it doesnt?  Very strange.  Ive been continuing to look for other answers but nothing seems to make sense

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.php?page=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @DanielRobinson Can you replace [L,QSA] with [R], make test and post (write it here with new comment) the url you have redirect to.

Comment: I get a redirect loop @MohammadAhmad      The web page at http://www.xample.co.uk/index.php/index.php?page=index.php&page=index.php&page=index.php&page= has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: Might I also say the root of the website is just www.example.co.uk/index.php

Comment: @DanielRobinson I have update my code, there have made small mistake, get new code above, and try again

Comment: thanks again @MohammadAhmad that now removes the variable completely and the page does not load because of it.  Ill show you the web address so you can see what I have properly.  www.crosbylakeside.co.uk

Comment: @DanielRobinson i'm double check my code and every thing working fine. Please post your complete .htaccess file.